# rails-i18n date_select error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-i18n

In my view I have:

`<%= f.date_select :start %>`

and I get the error message: `can't convert Symbol into String`

I know that it's related to `it.date.order` rule, but I see that `rails-i18n` include it:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/it.yml#L51

what's wrong here?

full back trace: https://gist.github.com/4007557

EDIT: running `I18n.t 'date.order'` in the console give me `=> [:day, :month, :year]`. That it's correct... so why `date_select` doesn't works?

issue on GitHub repo: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/issues/273

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar if not the same issue in the past. At the time I fixed it by using the following:

```
date:
  order: [ !ruby/symbol day, !ruby/symbol month, !ruby/symbol year ]
```

Comment: He has a problem with the I18n of the label of a form field, not with the I18n of the dateformat.

Comment: I already looked over the trace. I wouldn't had posted if I genuinely didn't thought it could solve the posters problem.

Comment: thank you @vise, this should solve the problem, but it doesn't explain why `date_select` is failing.

Comment: Solved my problem perfectly. Thanks. Anyone could explain what is the meaning of this line?

Answer (score 2):

This is a translation problem: you have to add `:order` rule to your `it.yml` file or use this line in form.

```
<%= f.date_select(:start, :order => [:day, :month, :year]) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the [rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) about `date_select` it wants to have a string.

If `:start` is the name of your I18n, you should do `<%= f.date_select t(:start) %>` as far as I remember.

Comment: Certainly true from what I remember too.

Comment: in my `config/locales/it.yml` I have `activerecord:
    attributes:
      project:
        start: Inizio
        stop: Fine`
and using `t(:start)` I get `undefined method <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: it.start">Start</span>' for #<Project:0x000000038662f0>`

Comment: and if if use `t(activerecord.attributes.project.start)` I get `undefined method 'Inizio' for Project`

Comment: Then you should have a look into http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations and use `t("activerecord.attributes.project.start")` instead. Or use `t(:start, :scope => [:activerecord, :attributes, :project])`

Comment: sorry, it's a typo. I used `t('activerecord.attributes.project.start')`. You could see that the app read `Inizio`, that it's correct, but I think that `date_select` needs the attribute (method) name `:start` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select

Comment: Take a look at the examples, there is never used a symbol! All examples are with strings, your errormessage says the same, you need a string! Use one! And I think I have understand now for the first time what `method` is meant to be, try `"start"` if the datefield in your model is `#start`… I will update the answer when you say if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to touch you form: it's a translation problem. You should add in your it.yml file the lines you will find here: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale.

Comment: Even though it's probably a better approach to use the whole rails-i18n gem.

Answer (score 1):

If like in my case you are only working with years and don't want to add translations for every language with i18n just for a year selection, you can add **:locale => 'en'** just for that date like this:

```
<%= f.date_select :start, :start_year => 1940, :end_year => Date.today.year, :discard_day => true, :discard_month => true, :locale => 'en' %>
```